# Change scrolling position of collection view, when view is currently not visible

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

There are two scenarios where I have problem with setting the scrolling position of my collection view:

- on start up I want to scroll to a certain item (starting position != beginning of the collection view)
- view is currently not visible yet, but in "background" the collection view should scroll to a certain item

What is a reliable way to scroll the collection view to a certain cell? Currently I'm setting the scrolling position with `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` in `viewDidAppear`, but that is too late for me.

Comment: how did u set the scrolling position? Are you using scrollToItemAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Did you try viewWillAppear too ?

Comment: @Mr.T: Yes, I use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`. I think I've tried `viewWillAppear`, but I will test it again. My main question here is, why can't I set the scrolling position at any time after creation?

Comment: sry, I didnt understand .WHat do u mean by scrolling position ? You can use scrollViewDIdScroll to change the scrollView.contentOffset.y , is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: In my collection view there are multiple cells. Not all are currently visible. At some times I have to change the position, so that other cells are visible. I do this with `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` to scroll to a certain cell (cells are in a distinct order so I know which one are visible and which not). But `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` is not doing, what it is intended to do. It stays on the last position and doesn't scroll to the new one, despite I'm telling it to do so. If I do that in `viewDidAppear` then it does work.

Comment: check my answer!!! @testing

Comment: Now I put my code into `viewWillAppear` and it doesn't work here, but `viewDidAppear` is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call the moethod in `viewDidLayoutSubview`:

Loooks like you cant scroll to item either in `viewWillAppear/DidAppear`!!!!

YOu can modify the `UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft` based on your collection view scroll direction

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:3 inSection:0]; //indexpath for the item to scroll

    [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];

}
```

**Swift:**

```
    func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.indexPathForItem(3, inSection: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: true)
}
```

The method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will get called only once, and it doesnt get called based on the collection view scroll!!!

Normally it will get called after `viewWillAppear` and before `viewDidAppear`!!

Comment: I think `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called too often (e.g. on scrolling). A mechanism is needed so that `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` is called only one time. This could be handled with a variable. I'm using view controller containment. Will `viewDidLayoutSubviews` be called if the user doesn't scroll and also the orientation didn't changed? Now I'm making some changes and tell you the results.

Comment: it will be called after viewWillAppear and before viewDidAppear.

Comment: You can call it manually wherever needed, i.e when you change the colleciton view frame, or colleciton view subview frames, then you should call layout subviews. Else, it is a one time call

Comment: Putting my code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` seems to work much nicer, because the user takes less notice of the scrolling. I'm using the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method in my parent view controller, which has the collection view controller added as child. So it is not directly on the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the collection view controller. I have to make my changes on multiple places. If that does work you get the tick.

Comment: I had to add some `layoutIfNeeded`, but now it works.

Comment: To force a layout early, you can call

`[self.collectionView setNeedsLayout]; [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CGPoint newContentOffset = yourCollectionView.contentOffset;
float offset = selectedIndex * (self.view.bounds.size.width + cellSpacing);
newContentOffset.x += offset;
yourCollectionView.contentOffset = newContentOffset;
```